# For loops in matlab with maximum and minimum pixel values

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have already uploaded the image. I need to answer below questions.

a.  Load the “cameraman” image. Convert it to a double array. Determine maximum (Imax) and the minimum (Imin) pixel value of the image
b.  Write a code to rescale the image such that all pixels with value< 1.25*Imin are equated to 1.25*Imin and all pixels with value > 0.75*Imax are equated to the 0.75*Imax.
c.  Display the new image.
 I have tried below codes but all I get is a black image.

```
**A = imread('D:\Matlab files\BRAIN 180\IMG-0002-00067.bmp','bmp')
 I = rgb2gray(A);
 I2 = double(I)/255;

 %subplot(2,2,1)
 %imshow(I2)

 Imin=min(I2(:))
 Imin

 Imax=max(I2(:))
 Imin

 for i=1:256
     for j=1:256
         if I2(i,j)<1.25;
             I2(i,j)=1.25*Imin;
         else
             I2(i,j)=0.75*Imax;
         end
     end
 end
 imshow(I2)**
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks for "value< 1.25*Imin" but in your code you wrote `I2(i,j)<1.25`, the Imin is missing.

Second problem, the condition "value > 0.75*Imax" is required by the question but not found in your code.

Comment: Indeed, `I2(i,j)<1.25` is always true.